# Adding mods to Minecraft on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: minecraft

So I have learned that there are no longer any bin folders or .minecraft folders on in the versions of minecraft 1.6 or higher.  I still want to add mods though.  Is there a way to add the mods of my choice without using Magic Launcher or the bin folder (since it doesn't exist)? All help is appreciated.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `.minecraft` folder, it's just hidden.

Everything that starts with a dot is hidden in Ubuntu (or any other Linux/UNIX OS).

To get in this folder:

1. Open your file manager
2. Click on `Home`
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
4. Search for `.minecraft` and open it
5. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> again to hide hidden files and folders

However there is no `minecraft.jar` anymore. You can now install multiple versions of Minecraft at the same time, so JARs have moved to `versions/1.7.9/1.7.9` for example.

Comment: Yes I understand that there isn't a bin folder any more or a minecraft.jar folder.  Is there another way to add the mods?  I'm kind of confused on what you mean by the versions and what not.

Comment: Yes, `minecraft.jar` has just moved. For example, if you're using 1.7.9, the location would be `.minecraft/versions/1.7.9/1.7.9.jar`. You can mod this file, but you can also just run the mod installer which will do this for you.

Comment: So what folder do I add the mod folder into?

Comment: This question isn't really related to Ubuntu anymore, but anyway. I assume you're using Forge Mod Loader. After you've installed Forge Mod Loader into the `.jar`, mods will be shared between all versions en should be placed in `.minecraft/mods`.

Comment: I can see the mods folder, but there is no .jar folder.

Comment: The `.jar` is not a folder... it's the file you should mod. See [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/zwxK6sA.png). I suggest you just download the installer [here](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php?action=files). First make sure you've Minecraft 1.7.2 installed, then download and run the installer called `1.7.2-Recommended`.

Comment: I just got it to work.  Thank you for your help!